# Let $x_n>a$ for all indices $n$, and $x_n \rightarrow b$. Prove $b \ge a$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question then is: Suppose $x_n>a$ for all indices $n$, and $lim x_n=b$. Prove that $b \ge a$.

My attempt: I am not going through contradiction-in-conclusion method (i.e. suppose $b<a$ since I think it doesn't **rigorously** mean $b \ge a$). Since $x_n>a$ so $|a-b|<|x_n-b|< \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, so $|a-b| \rightarrow 0$, i.e. $lim |a-b|=0$. But since $|a-b|$ is constant then $lim |a-b|=0 \implies |a-b|=0 \implies a=b$. Is that correct?

Thank you

Comment: You can just say that since $x_n>a$, so $\lim x_n \ge a$.

Comment: @Michael Galuza: if never $a<b$ how can we conclude $a\ge b$?

Comment: @AlphaE, surely you're joking. If never $a<b$, then $a=b$ or $a > b$; so...?

Comment: @Misakov - that's exactly what I am asking to be proved!

Comment: @AlphaE do you agree or disagree with the following statement: "for any $a,b$, we have $a<b$, $a=b$, or $a>b$."?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Yes! (PS - "If $x_n \ge a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\lim x_n \geq a$" has a proof in the book, but includes $=$, unfortunately. - "Order Limit Theorem" in here https://math.byu.edu/~bakker/M341/Lectures/Lec05.pdf includes '='

Comment: @AlphaE the same proof applies. If $x_n > a$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, then it certainly follows that $x_n \geq a$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Are you asking about the [law of trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics))?  This is usually taken as an axiom, and, therefore, isn't proven.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - my question is how $x>a$ implies $x \ge a$? $x>a$ means x may or may **not** equal to a. by "or" in $x \ge a$ i.e. x>a or x=a, we can't conclude the reverse. I mean $x \ge a$ definitely implies x>a **or** x=a, but x>a can't imply $x \ge a$. we don't have another 'information' possibility of equality.

Comment: @AlphaE if we know that $x > a$, then we definitely know that $x > a$ or $x = a$.  If we know that $x > a$ or $x = a$, then we don't have enough information to conclude that $x > a$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks a lot, I am convinced! Also, in Set Theory, if $a \in A \implies a\in A\cup B$ but the reverse may not be true.

Comment: @AlphaE It is strange to me that you find the set-theory argument more convincing, but whatever works...

Comment: Why you don't want to use contradictions? Let $b<a$; take $\epsilon = (b-a)/2$, and everything will be fine

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: Because I couldn't accept your statement "If never a<b, then a=b or a>b", but finally I could accept it. (Many thanks to @Omnomnomnom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of the things wrong with your proof:

- $|a - b| < |x_n - b|$: how did you come to that conclusion?
- $|x_n - b| < \epsilon$: this only makes sense here if you add something like "there exists an $N$ such that this holds for $n > N$".
- $\epsilon \to 0$: what??
- $|a - b| \to 0$: this doesn't make sense, or at least probably doesn't mean what you think it does; $a,b$ do not depend on $n$, so this is only true if $|a - b| = 0$.

---

Here's an outline of a valid proof (that doesn't use contradiction):

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $|x_n - b| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$.  However, $x_n > a$ for each $n$.  For all $\epsilon > 0$ and associated $n>N$, we therefore have
$$
b = (b - x_n) + x_n \geq - \epsilon + x_n > -\epsilon + a
$$
That is, we have $b > a - \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.  The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're wrong in that argument. What tells you that $|a-b|<|x_n-b|$.

Let $x_n=1$, $a=0.5$ and thus $b=1$. $|a-b|=0.5$, $|x_n-b|=0$. Thus, your argument is false.

As for the proof of the statement, here it goes:

Put $a_n=x_n-a$

$a_n>0\forall n$.

Let $\lim x_n=b$. Then

$\lim a_n=b-a$.

Assume $b<a$ and let $\varepsilon<a-b$

So, we have by definition of the limit:

$|a_n-(b-a)|<\varepsilon\forall n >N$. That is,

$-\varepsilon<a_n-(b-a)<\varepsilon$

Thus,

$a_n<\varepsilon+(b-a)<a-b+b-a=0$

That is $a_n<0\forall n>N$. Thus a contradiction, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to use contradiction to prove the statement:

Suppose that $x_n>a\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and that $\lim x_n=b\in \mathbb{R}$.

Now we assume that $a>b\Rightarrow$ There is a $k>0$ such that $b+k=a$. But
$\lim x_n=b\Rightarrow$ There is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-b|<k$ whenever $n>N$. We have two cases to investigate:

- If $x_n<b<a$ for some $n$ we have the desired contradiction, as $x_n>a$.
- If $x_n\geq b$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have: $$a=b+k>b+|x_{N+1}-b|=b+(x_{N+1}-b)=x_{N+1}\Rightarrow x_{N+1}<a.$$
  But $x_n>a$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so again we reach our contradiction.

Thus our initial assumption was false, and we're done.